# Three items in list to render side by side

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to get a list item with three data pieces appended side by side of each other. This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Currently my list looks like the below with the circle squashed.

[image]

```
//Rendering to DOM
<div className="Legend-Component col-3" align="center">
  {legendData.map((item, index) => (
     <ul key={index}>
        <li>
          <span>{item.name}</span>
          <span className={`${item.className[index]}`}></span>
          <span>{item.total}</span>
        </li>
     </ul>
   ))}
</div>
```

```
//CSS Style Sample
  .Legend-Component ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 1%;
      font-size: 12px;
  }
  .darkDot {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #79242F;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
  }
```

Comment: So, you are having problem with css?

Comment: For starters remove `align="center"`

Comment: This is a job for a css grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have specified the width and height tell it how to span by adding the display element to it.

The below code shows one of the possibilities

```
.darkDot {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background-color: #79242F;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```